# Invoke programmatically JasperReportsPdfView with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I've a Spring project and I'm using Spring MVC + JasperReportsPdfView to export pdf report to my client (JavaFx).

All works fine in the client but I need to get the pdf report also in a custom repository in the server (I want attach the pdf to an automatica email that the server send).
I don't know if this is possibile, and if yes which is the best practice to do that.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "tipoReport=2")
public ModelAndView exportFattura(@RequestParam(value = "idFattura", required = true) Long idFattura) throws Exception {
 ....
 ....
ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
model.addAttribute("format", "pdf");
return new ModelAndView("fattura", model);
}
```

and this is the view:

```
public class FatturaView extends JasperReportsMultiFormatView {
private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();


@Override
public String getUrl() {        
    return "classpath:report/Fattura.jasper";
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not a Spring developer but why not generate the pdf, save it on the server and then send the email... Generating to pdf should be fairly simple you need the jasper report lib+ the itext lib, Then do some batch that clears old file, or if you have control of the email sending, delete it after it has been sent

Comment: Just to reuse a standard and clean way to create pdf with Spring...

Comment: Anyone has some idea?